# Extending `z3` with one way functions

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I'm looking to use a one-way function in a `z3` Python program. I'd like z3 to respect the following properties/tactics:

- if `x = y`, then `f(x) = f(y)`
- `f` is a computable Python function that I can provide when `x` is known
- if `f(x) = y`, attempt to resolve by matching `f(*y) = f(x)` implying `x = *y` from prior assignments (never attempt to guess `x` that computes to `y`)

Are there built in features to support this construct or anything else that may help introduce it?

Comment: To a first extent, this looks like good old uninterpreted functions. But it's hard to tell from your description exactly what you are trying to achieve. If you can elaborate and tell us what you're trying to do, it might be easier to point out to resources.

Comment: Hi @LeventErkok, the drawback to uninterpreted functions is that `z3` has the "freedom" of solving for the function. In this case, I'm trying to model a SHA3 hash function and be able to solve equations like `sha3(sha3(x, y), z) == sha3(sha3(x, a), z)` without giving `z3` the power of changing what `sha3` means.

Comment: The typical way to do this is to put uninterpreted functions and quantified axioms about their behavior. That way you "restrict" their freedom. But SMT solvers don't deal with quantification all that well, so you often end up getting `unknown` as the answer. But that would be the only way to approach this problem in the SMT-solver parlance.

Comment: There's also the SMT `define-fun`, or Z3's macro-finder tactic (which inlines function definitions of the form `forall x . f(x) = …`)

Comment: Thanks both - I've seen in research similar axiomatizations complemented with instantiation schemes. Does that make things decidable again or just incrementally so?

Comment: @alias I ended up implementing this with quantified axioms and it worked fairly well.