# How to overload operators over GADTs in z3?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

**Objective**

My objective is to work in a theory where I have access to and can reason about integers and also have a known function `bar`.

I want to be able to solve equations like these:

```
bar(bar(x)) == bar(y)  Solution: y = bar(x), bar is unknown
2 + bar(2) == bar(x)   Solution: x is unknown, bar is unknown
```

The problem is that bar is ultimately computable but cannot be encoded in integer arithmetic, so I'm trying to map it to an "unknown" function.

**Particular example**

In `z3`, I'm working with the following custom data type.

```
import pytest
from z3 import Datatype, IntSort

def test_stackoverflow():
    FooBar = Datatype('FooBar')
    FooBar.declare('foo', ('unfoo', IntSort()))
    FooBar.declare('bar', ('unbar', FooBar))
    FooBar = FooBar.create()

    foo = FooBar.foo
    unfoo = FooBar.unfoo
    bar = FooBar.bar
    unbar = FooBar.unbar
```

Can I overload `+` operator to work across `foo` values like so:

`Forall([x, y], foo(x) + foo(y) == foo(x + y))`

Is there a way of doing this that doesn't sacrifice decidability?

Answer (score 0):

From a pure z3/SMTLib perspective: You cannot do this in SMTLib, or in the usual SMT-Lib parlance. If you want to add `FooBar`'s, you'll have to define a custom function for that.

From a "Python" perspective: I'm sure there's some Python magic incantation to overload the `+` for `FooBar` (you might have to hide it behind some class first), so it looks like regular addition. But keep in mind that this has nothing to do with Z3 or SMTLib, and it would be a mere Python trick.

Even if this is possible, I'd strongly advise against it: While overloading is cute, it almost always ends up causing more trouble than it's worth; and SMTLib is quite picky about how polymorphic things work: It only has "baked-in" polymorphism for symbols like `+`/`-` etc.; and in particular it expressly disallows user-defined polymorphism.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to "port" the operators over to operate on the GADT perhaps with other names?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "port." But there are many examples of how things are overloaded in the `z3.py` file itself, for instance see this: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/python/z3/z3.py#L2204-L2215 You can probably play similar games by first defining your own-class and adding an `__add__()` method. I think this is the only way to go about it.

Comment: I'm less interested in overloading an add method and more interested in being able to define an operator that works as addition as long as both values are `foo`s. Basically lets call this SpecialAdd. I want SpecialAdd(foo(x), foo(y)) to be foo(x + y). It doesn't matter if SpecialAdd is '+'or has another name.

Comment: I'm still trying to essentially answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536062/extending-z3-with-one-way-functions. Uninterpreted functions aren't going to work because z3 wants to redefine them at liberty, but what I'm trying to do now is create a space of values where my one-way function is a first-class citizen. The problem is I still need to be able to apply traditional operators.

Comment: The only way is to use uninterpreted functions, with quantified axioms. You of course then have the problem of semi-decidability and the solver responding back `unknown`. You can also specify quantifier instantiation patterns directly from your Python code, see here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/python/z3/z3.py#L1725-L1785

But all this is quite fragile and I doubt you'll get any mileage especially if you're trying to axiomatize some cryptographic functions. I'd love to hear if you find otherwise!

Comment: I'm assuming the uninterpreted function approach would not work because the whole point of uninterpreted functions is to solve for the functions themselves? The only axiom I could think of is one to prove that f(x) is never equal to any integer.

```
    solver = Solver()
    bar = Function('bar', IntSort(), IntSort())

    x, y = Ints('x y')
    solver.add(ForAll([x, y], bar(x) != y))
    assert str(solver.check()) == "unsat"
```

Can you clarify what axioms you would instantiate here?

Comment: @Peteris: I don't quite understand your original question perhaps. It's much easier to talk about concrete examples. Perhaps you can come up with a different question on a specific concrete (and hopefully simpler than original) case in a different question? Extended comments are not very production in stackoverflow.

Comment: Completely agree - I posted a clarification in the original question above! My only intent is to be able to model problems that use a function that I know but cannot be encoded in Z3.